# Define all visible cells are in a row of a range to a in sequence

Tags: vba, excel

I need defines each `Cells` are in a range row in sequence If confront a Hidden column.
In pointed area of code below, when reached a hidden column in the specific row, jump to next row and at last refer to continue of this row and assign to RngCell variable.

**I want when `For Each` loop reached a hided column, continue the cells assigning to next visible cell of appropriated row.**

```
Sub CsvExportRange(rngRange As Range, strFileName As Variant, strCharset As String)

    Dim rngRow As Range
    Dim objStream As Object

    Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    objStream.Type = 2
    objStream.Charset = strCharset
    objStream.Open

    OffColumns (True)
    Call Tax_WP

    For Each rngRow In rngRange.Rows 'The problem becuase Here
        objStream.WriteText CsvFormatRow(rngRow) 
    Next rngRow

    objStream.SaveToFile strFileName, 2
    objStream.Close
End Sub
Function CsvFormatRow(rngRow As Range) As String

    Dim arrCsvRow() As String
    Dim strRowEnd As String

    strRowEnd = vbCrLf

    ReDim arrCsvRow(rngRow.Cells.Count - 1)
    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim lngIndex As Long

    lngIndex = 0

    For Each rngCell In rngRow.Cells '***Problem is Here***
        arrCsvRow(lngIndex) = CsvFormatString(rngCell.Value)
        lngIndex = lngIndex + 1
    Next rngCell


    CsvFormatRow = Join(arrCsvRow, ",") & vbCrLf

End Function
Function CsvFormatString(strRaw As String) As String

    Dim boolNeedsDelimiting As Boolean

    Dim strDelimiter, strSeparator, strDelimiterEscaped As String

    strDelimiter = """"
    strSeparator = strSeparator = ","
    strDelimiterEscaped = strDelimiter & strDelimiter

    boolNeedsDelimiting = InStr(1, strRaw, strDelimiter) > 0 _
        Or InStr(1, strRaw, chr(10)) > 0 _
        Or InStr(1, strRaw, strSeparator) > 0

    CsvFormatString = strRaw

    If boolNeedsDelimiting Then
        CsvFormatString = strDelimiter & _
            Replace(strRaw, strDelimiter, strDelimiterEscaped) & _
            strDelimiter
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: did you try `For Each rngCell In rngRow.SpecialCells(12)`?

Comment: I edited my question by add `'The problem because Here` comment. Seems in this point, only get first sequenced visible rows as a line to variable. but I need assign all visible cells on each line to variable as a line.

Comment: Then try also `For Each rngRow In rngRange.SpecialCells(12).Rows`

Comment: Run-time Error. No cells where found in `For Each rngRow In rngRange.SpecialCells(12).Rows` line

Comment: What?? that means all your rows were filtered out!?

Comment: No. in specified range, there where some rows has filtered columns

Comment: I don't have any view over your range and how it was filtered. Maybe if you post some snapshots of the data and/or more code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a hard time understanding what you want to happen when you encounter a hidden column. In your post you say "jump to next row", but then in bold, you say, "continue the cells assigning to next visible cell of appropriated row" which is unclear but might mean you wish to continue on the row, but skip the hidden column?

You also use an array combined with `rngRow.Cells.Count - 1` which is always going to get you 16,383 to define your array. It might be easier if you dynamically updated your array while you looped through your rows, or simply string together your text to a single variable?

Are you ultimately trying to avoid a bunch of ",,"? If so, this method may work better.

In summary, the below code will:

- End your CSVFormatRow function when `rngCell` is in a hidden column.
- End your CSVFormatRow function when `rngCell` is in a column that is outside CSV file's used range of ANY row (not just the row it's looping through).
- Instead of using an array, the code just string together members to variable `StrinCVSRow`
- Exclude the final `,` in `StrinCVSRow`

If that doesn't address your question, please clarify the requirements. Hope this helps.

```
Function CsvFormatRow(rngRow As Range) As String

    'Dim arrCsvRow() As String

    Dim StrinCVSRow As String 'new variable to string row text together.

    Dim strRowEnd As String 'these two lines aren't doing anything
    strRowEnd = vbCrLf      'these two lines aren't doing anything

    'ReDim arrCsvRow(rngRow.Cells.Count - 1) ' always equals 16383
    Dim rngCell As Range

    'Dim lngIndex As Long ' (not needed if Array omitted)

    'lngIndex = 0

    For Each rngCell In rngRow.Cells '***Problem is Here***
        If rngCell.EntireColumn.Hidden = True Then
            'The "Exit For" will end the code here and jump to next row.
            'If you wanted to continue through the row you can leave
            'this condition in, but delete the "Exit For"
            'and this will simply "skip" this particular column.
            Exit For
        ElseIf Intersect(rngCell, Sheets(rngCell.Sheet.Name).UsedRange) Is Nothing Then
            'ends loop if last column with any data in entire CSV file is reached.
            Exit For

        Else
            StrinCVSRow = CsvFormatString(rngCell.Value) & ","
     '       lngIndex = lngIndex + 1
        End If

    Next rngCell

    'CsvFormatRow = Join(arrCsvRow, ",") & vbCrLf

    'left function trims off final ",".
    CsvFormatRow = Left(StrinCVSRow, Len(StrinCVSRow) - 1) & vbCrLf

End Function
```

Comment: With truly thanks, I found the problem's root is in `For Each rngRow In rngRange.Rows 'The problem because Here`, which not assign completely `Rane`'s line to `rngRow` and first assign first segment (first visible domain of range) of each line, after that start assigning second segment (second visible domain after first hided column(s) ) of lines are in `range` up to last segments are in lines in `Range`. I needed assigning all of visible line cells are in each range line at each assigning time with `For Each rngRow In rngRange.Rows` to create true form of complete CSV record in `Join` command

Comment: I solved the problem by changing assigning method from `for each` command that was generating above said unknown problem, to same `for` loop and will post my revision, at tomorrow from my office. with great thanks.

Comment: Tomorow and after posting my answer, please say about that problem was in `for each` at `For Each rngRow In rngRange.Rows` line (and its reason - possible true revision) that faced me to said bug!

Comment: **I M P O R T A N T:** Passed `Range` in `Sub CsvExportRange(rngRange As Range, ...` is generating with `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` for creating a range contained only visible cells. (As  [A.S.H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4926357/a-s-h) briefly said in comments are under major question). I will represent integrated compose of `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` and major initial range in my reached solution as an answer in tomorrow post.

Comment: Your English is pretty difficult to follow, but what I'm understanding you're saying is... "Thank PGCodeRider, but your post is not helpful. Inspired by a comment from ASH, I miraculously figured this out on my own and am going to post/recognize an answer to my own question tomorrow."  Awesome....

Answer (score -1):

In code bellow I reached a way that truly catch all visible cells are in a table row with integrating `SpecialCells(12)`, `Fore each` and `For i`:

(with writing inserting comments in above positions)

```
Sub CsvExportRange(rngRange As Object, strFileName As String, strCharset As String)

    Dim rngRow As Range
    Dim objStream As Object
    Dim i, lngFR As Long 'First Row

    lngFR = rngRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows(1).Row - rngRange.Rows(1).Row + 1 'giving absolute Row number of first Table's row.

    Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    objStream.Type = 2
    objStream.Charset = strCharset
    objStream.Open
    For i = lngFR To lngFR + rngRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count - 1
        objStream.WriteText CsvFormatRow(rngRange.Rows(i)) 'Gives all visible lines are in table entirely of sheet. (Here using Fore i... is suitable)
    Next i

    objStream.SaveToFile strFileName, 2
    objStream.Close
End Sub
Function CsvFormatRow(rngRow As Variant) As String

    Dim arrCsvRow() As String
    Dim strRowEnd As String

    strRowEnd = vbCrLf

    ReDim arrCsvRow(rngRow.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1) 'Defining array dimension for saving each cell in a array room and at last using Join() command
    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim lngIndex As Long

    lngIndex = 0

    For Each rngCell In rngRow.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells 'Here we used For Each to give only visible cells of above entire line so thats line is there in Table range.
        arrCsvRow(lngIndex) = CsvFormatString(rngCell.Value)
        lngIndex = lngIndex + 1
    Next rngCell

    CsvFormatRow = Join(arrCsvRow, ",") & vbCrLf 'At last, here generating destination CSV file data file.

End Function
Function CsvFormatString(strRaw As String) As String

    Dim boolNeedsDelimiting As Boolean

    Dim strDelimiter, strSeparator, strDelimiterEscaped As String

    strDelimiter = """"
    strSeparator = strSeparator = ","
    strDelimiterEscaped = strDelimiter & strDelimiter

    boolNeedsDelimiting = InStr(1, strRaw, strDelimiter) > 0 _
        Or InStr(1, strRaw, chr(10)) > 0 _
        Or InStr(1, strRaw, strSeparator) > 0

    CsvFormatString = strRaw

    If boolNeedsDelimiting Then
        CsvFormatString = strDelimiter & _
            Replace(strRaw, strDelimiter, strDelimiterEscaped) & _
            strDelimiter
    End If

End Function
```